# Replace all html attribute definitions that use single quotes with double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an html string and I want to replace any instance of an html attribute being set with single quotes with double quotes.

So for example, I want to replace

```
<script src='foo.js'></script>
```

with

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
```

However, I want to do this without affecting any single quotes that might be in javascript statements or in text within the html.

Eg

```
<script> var foo = '67'; </script>
```

should be unaffected and

```
<div id='foo'> 'hi' </div>
```

should become

```
<div id="foo"> 'hi' </div>
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

For a given element selecting it with jquery and then reading its outerHTML does this but I want to do it to an entire page of html all at once.

Thanks!

Comment: It will require extreme regular expressions

Comment: and, you'd better hope your HTML is well formed.

Comment: outerHTML?  So you're manipulating the HTML inside the browser? What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Seems like you already answered your own question. Let the DOM convert them for you ....  `$('body').html()`  or `$('html').html()` will retrieve head and body

Comment: I'm curious: _why_ do you want to do this? _"I want to do it to an entire page of html all at once"_ - Do you mean you want to do it for the html of the page that is already loaded into the browser?

Comment: i am getting an html string from an ajax request and manipulating it in the browser before rendering it.

Comment: So what is the point of changing single quotes to doubles when both are valid? Perhaps if you showed the JavaScript code for your Ajax success handler it would give people something to work with.

Comment: @charlietfl I think you basically are right, I just am not sure how to make jquery give me that because what I have from my ajax request is a string.  Doing, $(htmlString).html(); gives me null even though doing something like $(htmlString).siblings("script") lists all the script tags.

Comment: try  `alert( $('<div>').html(htmlString).html() );`

Comment: I agree with @nnnnnn -- *why* do you want to do this?  Do you want to do this on the client side or on the server side?

Comment: @charlietfl maybe i'm misunderstanding but that doesn't seem to work, it gives a "cannot call method html of null error, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QdUR5/

Comment: The why is quite complex, I'm making a pretty unique web application and I need to significantly alter a page client side.  Think of something like JSFiddle where the user is entering html on the fly and then the contents is being rendered in an iframe.

Comment: problem with your string is tags like `html`, 'head`, 'body` etc are not valid child of div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question as I think the easiest solution to this is what is shown in this fiddle and does not require jquery or regexps:

http://jsfiddle.net/QdUR5/1/

```
<html id="foo"></html>​
var htmlString = 
  '<head>' +
  '<script type="text/javascript" src=\'main.js\'></scr' + 'ipt>' +
  '</head>' +
  '<body onload=\'onLoad()\'>' +
  '</body>' ;

document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = htmlString;
console.log(document.getElementById('foo').outerHTML);
```

​

Basically you just need to set the inner html of an html element to the html string without the html tags and then output the html elements outer html.

I think that is a bit simpler than using a regexp although that is an awesome regexp Mike :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "<br style   = 'width:100px'/>   test link<a href=\"http://www\"></a>";
var regex = /<\w+\s*(\w+\s*=\s*(['][^']*['])|(["][^"]*["]))*\s*[\/]?>/g;
var rstr = str.replace(regex, function($0,$1,$2){
    return $0.replace($2, $2.replace(/'/g, '"'));
});
console.log('replaced string = ' + rstr);
```

You can refector it to strictly match your case.